# WooCommerce category URL modification

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

My shop page's URL looks like this: `example.com/shop/`

Category URLs look like this: `example.com/category/sweatshirts/`

I need them to look like this: `example.com/shop/category/sweatshirts/`

I tried to edit setting from WP permalinks **Product category base** but then the category show 404 page.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Under Settings -> Permalinks -> Product Permalinks tick "Shop base with category" and Save Changes.

[Settings for Permalinks with shop base and category in url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEGlH.png)